# Number of SHA-1 Iterations?

Tags: php, hash, sha

I'm currently working with an API system that requires all variables to be submitted using SHA-1 hashes with 38,000 iterations.  Their API system and my script uses PHP.

Here's my question:  is there a specific reason to use a certain number of iterations?

I'm not asking necessarily for this API, but would like to know for future reference.  Why not use just 20,000 iterations or as many as 50,000?  Is there any sort of "limit" on how many should be used?

Comment: I'm not sure, at first I thought that it could be a time thing to deter brute force attacks, but if that were true, why use SHA-1 and not something like Bcrypt. I am interested in the answer though.

Comment: Everything I've researched points towards iterations being used to slow down brute force attacks as well.  I know there are other options like Bcrypt, but I am wondering what the limits on SHA-1 iterations would be and why a company would choose specifically 38,000 iterations.